# iOS cannot open downloaded MS Word files

Tags: ios, swift, openurl

I am trying to open MS Word file in iOS app.

My code:

```
var wordFilePath = "ms-word:ofv|u|file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F81C/Documents/%AD%D8%B3%D9%85.docx"

let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: wordFilePath)

if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:]) { result in
    }
}
```

The `canOpenUrl` returns true and my app executes `open` method but nothing happens, no app opened the file. No logs in Xcode log console.

`plist` file has the following snippet:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>ms-word</string>
</array>
```

Comment: The word app can't access a file in your app's sandbox.

Comment: @Paulw11 Can I gave permission to other apps in iOS?

Comment: No. You need to use UIDocument interactions to expose the file to the other app

Comment: @Paulw11 which directory is good to download word files into so that all apps can read it? I currently download to `FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory`

Comment: You can't just put the files in a directory; Apps on iOS are sandboxed.  You can use [`UIDocumentInteractionController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller) to allow your app to open the file in another app